# Wrapping my head around effecient solutions to copy-pasting chunks of code

Tags: xslt

Coming from a language like PHP, I naturally hate copy and pasting code over and over changing but a single variable or value. I have a series of code chunks in an XSLT that are copy and pasted over and over looking for a specific node value, and then doing something.

I start with this chunk, which is uses to populate a list of names for each function:

```
<xsl:variable name="<!-- VARIABLE OF NAMES -->">
    <xsl:for-each select="//<!-- FUNCTIONS -->">
        <xsl:for-each select="./<!-- USER FUNCTIONS -->">
            <xsl:if test="<!-- SPECIFIC FUNCTION -->">
            <xsl:value-of select="Title"/>
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="FirstName"/>
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="LastName"/>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

Here is the logic I use to grab:

```
<xsl:if test="<!-- SPECIFIC LIST OF USERS THAT HAVE A FUNCTION HAPPEN TO THEM -->">
    <xsl:call-template name="<!-- SPECIFIC TEMPLATE FOR IT -->">
        <xsl:with-param name="listOfNames">
            <xsl:value-of select="<!-- FUNCTION THAT GRABS A LIST OF NAMES -->" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>
        </xsl:with-param>
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:if>
```

Later I use the following chunk of code to display the results:

```
<xsl:template name="<!-- SPECIFIC TEMPLATE -->">
    <xsl:param name="listOfNames"/>
    <!-- DO SPECIFIC STUFF -->
</xsl:template>
```

I have wracked my brain looking at this and I just can't get my head around a way of doing this more recursively. Or at the very least stop me copy and pasting the same three chunks of code for every function (Of which there is like 18)...

I know this isn't a "post your code and get it sorted" board but I seriously think there is a better way to do this but god help me I can't see it.

Here is an example of the XML that this part of the XSLT works with:

```
<UserUpdated>
    <UserDetails>
        <Title>MR</Title>
        <FirstName>TEST</FirstName>
        <LastName>EVO</LastName>
    </UserDetails>
</UserUpdated>
<FlightServicingFunction>FUNCTIONNAME</FlightServicingFunction>
<FlightServicingFunction>FUNCTIONNAME</FlightServicingFunction>
<FlightServicingFunction>.... (Continues per function that has to be done to user)
```

Let me know if you need more information. Thanks in advance to any and all help.

Here is an example: http://xsltransform.net/pPqsHSZ

Comment: XSLT cannot be compared to PHP and works differently. The common usage of if/else, for-each etc. in XSLT can be simplified with the template concept of XSLT combined with XPath. To be able to help you, please provide a small input XML and the desired output XML, and Stackoverflow will show you how to do it!

Comment: Recursion is not the same as _reusing_ your code to avoid redundancy. What do you mean by "doing this more recursively"? Also, you will only get good answers if you post a full XSLT stylesheet, together with an XML input and output.

Comment: Yeah, my english failed me I think. I mean effecient I guess? @FiveO I know they are different languages, but I can't stop my brain wanting to approach them with the same principles. I know that its a fallacy and they aren't the same but reagardless I hate copy-pasting code! I'll provide an example of the XML, updating now.

Comment: I appreciate your effort but that's still not very insightful. Can you post a _full_ XSLT stylesheet (i.e. one that can be handed to an XSLT processor without making changes or adding something) where your problem is present, together with a _well-formed_ XML input that corresponds to the stylesheet. That would make it much clearer.

Comment: Hard to tell from the scanty information given, but I suspect the problem might lie in the design of your data rather than in your code. Perhaps the data has an intrinsic structure which isn't explicit and is therefore hard to manipulate.

Comment: I have added an example link for you guys. Here you can see the work in action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This XSLT is typically produced by people who learned the syntax but not the concepts. It is the typical pull-style that is produced by people who know what the input will be, and the mindset is automatically to *pull* data from it.

The proper way to use XSLT is to be as oblivious to the input as possible, and only specifiy templates for the specific tags that you care about. This is a *push* style transformation. Your current XSLT relies on `xsl:for-each` to loop over input tags and then use `xsl:if` to see if the tag matches what you want.

Instead, you should use `xsl:apply-templates` with a generic `select` (using a lot of wildcards) in combination with multiple `xsl:template`s, each with a specific match.

Since you didn't specify any exact input or output, here's a concept that should get you started:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="//FlightServicingFunction" />
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="FlightServicingFunction[. = '<!--specific function-->']">
    <xsl:value-of select="Title"/>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="FirstName"/>
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
    <xsl:value-of select="LastName"/>
</xsl:template>
```

You'd still have to copy-paste the `xsl:template match="..."` bit a couple of times, but you get rid of the aggressive looping this way in order to make the XSLT processor do it for you. That is what it was designed for.

The trick to getting the rest of the data (the stuff that you currently put in variables) is to conquer their relative position in the nodeset you are matching and use a good XPath to select it. It provides ample tools to get anything you want, whatever the active node is.

Further suggested reading: http://www.usingxml.com/Transforms/XslIdentity. Good luck!

Comment: http://xsltransform.net/bdxtpG - Is this something more along of the lines of what you would suggest then?

Comment: @Aleski that is **starting** to look more like it, but _why_ are you using `call-template` **within** your template? You are **already** in a template, and the things you put in the variable are available at that point. Better put the output in there straight away!

Comment: @Aleski Better, but there's really no need to call named templates. Please explain to us _what_ you are trying to achieve, given the XML input.

Comment: @aleski http://xsltransform.net/gWmuiHT/6 -> I removed your superfluous template call and used a single XPath to get the value you want, for the first template. Your turn to adapt your other templates to it!

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester Well after each function is found, I somehow need to populate a variable of some sort with the passenger list. This is to be used in a resource bundle so i will pass the bundle `$passengerList`. Im not sure If I can do that inside the same template... Or can I? (again, apologies for witholding information, I guess I wanted to be more broad than specific but its just causing headaches!)

Comment: @Aleski seems like that is a global variable? If so, you can define it outside any template and select what you need with absolute paths (starting with `/`). You can then simply do `value-of select="$passengerList/my/selector"` to place something from it in the output, or `copy-of select="$passengerList"` to copy the whole set into the output.

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester Unfortunately I can't define it outside. It needs to be pulled from within the template.

Comment: @Aleski Perhaps the single best thing you can do is - read up on XSLT! There are many good introductions to XSLT (explaining functional programming, not only the syntax). It is obvious that you did not take a lot of time to familiarize yourself with the concepts.

Comment: @MathiasMüller I know that this is the most obvious thing. I missed out on a lot of the conceptual side of the language over the functional side. This has helped greatly though so I must thank everyone who has contributed. It has gave me a nice new perspective on the problem. - I have some reading to do!

Comment: @MDeSchaepmeester The only problem I have now is why the first instance of the text is not indented? http://xsltransform.net/gWmuiHT/8